# Puppeteer can't click sign-in button

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer, headless

Currently building a puppeteer program that allows me to sign in to a website, however, after inputting login, I can not seem to make puppeteer click the sign-in button or any button for that matter.I have used dev tools, hovered over the button in question, and input its class ="sign-in-button" but it still does not work on the headless browser I am running. It says on the error sheet that there is no node found for selector: button[type=submit]. It is my third day coding, would love any assistance I can get. Thank you! Please leave any suggestions below, I want to know how to make puppeteer click buttons on screen, but I am having trouble.

Note: I have tried await page.$eval("button[class='sign-in-button']", elem => elem.click());
did not work..

[sign-in-button when hovered over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ehF.png)

[this is what it says in elements in dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMoXy.png)

Comment: Please share a link to the site you're manipulating or a [mcve] recreation of that site, with your full (but minimized) code. When a selector isn't found, there could be any number of possible causes due to dynamic JS/CSS behavior, and the information here isn't enough to definitively determine what might be the problem. Sometimes you need to `waitForSelector(..., {visible: true})`, sometimes the hitbox isn't something Puppeteer's internal `.click()` can click on, and many other possibilities. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selector points to a `button` element instead to an `input` element and is therefore not found.

Changing the selector to this should work:

```
await page.$eval("input[class='sign-in-button']", elem => elem.click());
```

###### Short class selector

Alternatively you could just select it via classname, so if the `input` element would be changed to a `button` element the code would not break. Whenever you pu a dot `.` before a css selector it automatically treats it as class selector.

```
await page.$eval(".sign-in-button", elem => elem.click());
```

##### JS handle

Instead of clicking the element within the browser context (`DOM`) you could use `page.$` for receiving a button handle and click that.

```
// use $ method for receiving a handle to your sign-in button/input
const btn = await page.$('.sign-in-button')

// click it using the `puppeteer` api instead of native DOM clicking.. 
btn.click()
```

Comment: Thank you! I did the await page.$eval("input[class='sign-in-button']", elem => elem.click()); and it worked.

Comment: I was doing await page.$eval("button[class.... rather than using "input[class...